# CSS class for pointer cursor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is there any CSS class or attribute for `pointer:cursor` in [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) specially for button or link?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sample Button</button>
```

Answer (score 323, accepted):

As of June 2020, adding `role='button'` to any HTML tag would add `cursor: "pointer"` to the element styling.

```
<span role="button">Non-button element button</span>
```

Official discussion on this feature - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23709

Documentation link - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/reboot/#pointers-on-buttons

Comment: Be aware that although this may work, you should only use it when the role of the element is being a button.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer, as it add the cursor but not other classes related to 'buttons'

Comment: I can confirm that this works and has been present since Bootstrap 3 at least.

Comment: Bootstrap 5.2. it works.

Answer (score 77):

Unfortunately there is no such class in Bootstrap as of now (27th Jan 2019).

I scanned through bootstrap code and discovered following classes that use **cursor: pointer**. Seems like it is not a good idea to use any of them specifically for cursor: pointer.

```
summary {
  display: list-item;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5rem;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.custom-range::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5rem;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.custom-range::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5rem;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0.5rem;
}
.navbar-toggler:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.page-link:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}
```

**The only OBVIOUS SOLUTION:**

What I would suggest you is just to create a class in your common css as `cursor-pointer`. That is simple and elegant as of now.

```css
.cursor-pointer{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor-pointer">Hover on  me</div>
```

Comment: Simply add an attribute `role="button"` to HTML elements you like to have a pointer cursor when the mouse cursor is hovering the elements.

Answer (score 72):

### UPDATE for Bootstrap 4 stable

The `cursor: pointer;` rule has been restored, so buttons will now by default have the cursor on hover:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sample Button</button>
```

---

No, there isn't. You need to make some custom CSS for this.

If you just need a link that looks like a button (with pointer), use this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button">Sample Button</a>
```

Comment: I've accomplished the effect by simply adding: role="button" ... No need for the btn class.

Comment: FYI: disabled state is broken for buttons (has pointer) but works for links (no pointer): tested at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/buttons/ in FF76 and same behavior in my app using webjar's 4.4.1-1

Answer (score 52):

You can assign `button` to role attribute of any html tag/element to make pointer over it.

```html
<html-element role="button" />
```

Comment: copy of Vibhor Dube's answer?!

Answer (score 37):

I usually just add the following custom CSS, the [W3School example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor) prepended with `cursor-`

```css
.cursor-alias {cursor: alias;}
.cursor-all-scroll {cursor: all-scroll;}
.cursor-auto {cursor: auto;}
.cursor-cell {cursor: cell;}
.cursor-context-menu {cursor: context-menu;}
.cursor-col-resize {cursor: col-resize;}
.cursor-copy {cursor: copy;}
.cursor-crosshair {cursor: crosshair;}
.cursor-default {cursor: default;}
.cursor-e-resize {cursor: e-resize;}
.cursor-ew-resize {cursor: ew-resize;}
.cursor-grab {cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: grab;}
.cursor-grabbing {cursor: -webkit-grabbing; cursor: grabbing;}
.cursor-help {cursor: help;}
.cursor-move {cursor: move;}
.cursor-n-resize {cursor: n-resize;}
.cursor-ne-resize {cursor: ne-resize;}
.cursor-nesw-resize {cursor: nesw-resize;}
.cursor-ns-resize {cursor: ns-resize;}
.cursor-nw-resize {cursor: nw-resize;}
.cursor-nwse-resize {cursor: nwse-resize;}
.cursor-no-drop {cursor: no-drop;}
.cursor-none {cursor: none;}
.cursor-not-allowed {cursor: not-allowed;}
.cursor-pointer {cursor: pointer;}
.cursor-progress {cursor: progress;}
.cursor-row-resize {cursor: row-resize;}
.cursor-s-resize {cursor: s-resize;}
.cursor-se-resize {cursor: se-resize;}
.cursor-sw-resize {cursor: sw-resize;}
.cursor-text {cursor: text;}
.cursor-w-resize {cursor: w-resize;}
.cursor-wait {cursor: wait;}
.cursor-zoom-in {cursor: zoom-in;}
.cursor-zoom-out {cursor: zoom-out;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success cursor-pointer">Sample Button</button>
```

Answer (score 15):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the relevant answers, but to people reading this; adding .btn does not just add the pointer cursor but adds [a lot of other styling](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_buttons.scss) as well. Which is great if it's a button and you want the bootstap button styling, but in other cases it would mess a lot up for other elements.

The best thing you can do, [like Hari Das suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54391421/6234444), and which I also always do, is to add the following css:

```
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

After which you can add it to any element

```
<div class="cursor-pointer"> .. </div>
```

Comment: bootstrap 4.3 has fixed this problem already
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/#examples

Answer (score 6):

I tried and found out that if you add a class called `btn` you can get that `hand` or `cursor` icon if you hover over the mouse to that element. Try and see.

Example:

```
<span class="btn">Hovering over must have mouse cursor set to hand or pointer!</span>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 3 - Just adding the "**btn**" Class worked for me.

**Without** pointer cursor:

```
<span class="label label-success">text</span>
```

**With** pointer cursor:

```
<span class="label label-success btn">text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know when added but according to its doc there is `btn-link`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Click Me, Hover Me Link</button>
 <body> 
 </html>
```

Link

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

[btn-link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 1):

**Try to use type = button**
`<span type="button">Hover me</span>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no classes for that. But you can add inline style for your div or other elements
like,

```
<div class="" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: this is valid html but it's not needed: the update to the accepted answer to this question notes Bootstrap 4 Stable now handles this out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You could use either one of the followings to get your job done:

1st: use `type=button`;

```
<!-- display as a link -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Click Me, Hover Me Link</button> 

<!-- display as a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me, Hover Me Link</button>
```

2nd: use anchor and `role=button`;

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Click Me, Hover Me Link</a>
```

either way, once you hover you will see hand ...